# Is there a way to get current HTML from browser in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I am currently working on a HTML presentation, that works well, but I need the presentation to be followed simultaneously with a NAO robot who reads a special  html tag. I somehow need to let him know, which slide I am on, so that he can choose the correct  tag.

I use Beautiful Soup for scraping the HTML, but it does so from a file and not from a browser. The problem is, there is javascript running behind, assigning various classes to specific slides, that tell the current state of the     presentation. And I need to be able to access those, but in the default state of the presentation they are not present and are added asynchronously throughout the process of the presentation.

Hopefully, my request is clear.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

http://www.seleniumhq.org/ (probably webdriver) is your friend. Initialize a browser and call browser.html to get the document in the current state.

Comment: I tried it, but it still gets only the html of the static file, it is a shame, it looked like it could work finally :/

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but you can tell the browser to wait for certain events to occur, or actually cause them to occur executing javascript (webdriver wait / executeScript() method)

Answer (score 0):

There's wget on the robot, you could use it... (though I'm not sure I understand where is really the problem...)